# Not able to run chromium as service

Tags: linux, debian, systemd, chrome

I'm trying to run a chromium as a service cause I need the pulseaudio is running.

The service file is:

```
[Unit]
Description = Kiosk launcher as service
After = pulseaudio.service
Wants =
Requires =

[Service]
Type = simple
PIDFile = /var/run/kiosk.pid
ExecStart = /usr/bin/chromium --no-sandbox /var/www/Kiosk/trunk/indexLocker.php
Restart = on-abort
StartLimitInterval = 60
StartLimitBurst = 10

[Install]
WantedBy =
```

I run the `systemctl start kiosk` but nothing happen.
The output of the status option is:

```
● kiosk.service - Kiosk launcher as service
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/kiosk.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2022-07-21 17:38:37 CEST; 8s ago
Process: 9283 ExecStart=/usr/bin/chromium --no-sandbox /var/www/Kiosk/trunk/indexLocker.php (code=exited, sta    
Main PID: 9283 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jul 21 17:38:37 tinkerboard systemd[1]: kiosk.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

---

I write here just to display better the outputs:

```
linaro@tinkerboard:~/.config/systemd/user$ ls -la
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 2 linaro linaro 4096 Jul 22 09:22 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 linaro linaro 4096 Jul 21 17:11 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 linaro linaro  327 Jul 22 09:22 kiosk.service
linaro@tinkerboard:~/.config/systemd/user$ 
linaro@tinkerboard:~/.config/systemd/user$ systemctl --user start kiosk
Failed to start kiosk.service: Unit kiosk.service not found.
linaro@tinkerboard:~/.config/systemd/user$ 
linaro@tinkerboard:~/.config/systemd/user$ echo $HOME
/home/linaro
linaro@tinkerboard:~/.config/systemd/user$ whoami
linaro
linaro@tinkerboard:~/.config/systemd/user$
```

I'm sorry but I'm not able to see the problem ..

--- ADDED ---

```
linaro@tinkerboard:~/.config/systemd/user$ strace -e trace=file systemctl --user start kiosk > output
execve("/bin/systemctl", ["systemctl", "--user", "start", "kiosk"], [/* 39 vars */]) = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/systemd/tls/v7l/neon/vfp/libsystemd-shared-232.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/systemd/tls/v7l/neon/vfp", 0xbed08cc0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/systemd/tls/v7l/neon/libsystemd-shared-232.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/systemd/tls/v7l/neon", 0xbed08cc0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/systemd/tls/v7l/vfp/libsystemd-shared-232.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/systemd/tls/v7l/vfp", 0xbed08cc0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/systemd/tls/v7l/libsystemd-shared-232.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/systemd/tls/v7l", 0xbed08cc0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/systemd/tls/neon/vfp/libsystemd-shared-232.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/systemd/tls/neon/vfp", 0xbed08cc0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/systemd/tls/neon/libsystemd-shared-232.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/systemd/tls/neon", 0xbed08cc0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/systemd/tls/vfp/libsystemd-shared-232.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/systemd/tls/vfp", 0xbed08cc0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/systemd/tls/libsystemd-shared-232.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/systemd/tls", 0xbed08cc0)  = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/systemd/v7l/neon/vfp/libsystemd-shared-232.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/systemd/v7l/neon/vfp", 0xbed08cc0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/systemd/v7l/neon/libsystemd-shared-232.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/systemd/v7l/neon", 0xbed08cc0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/systemd/v7l/vfp/libsystemd-shared-232.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/systemd/v7l/vfp", 0xbed08cc0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/systemd/v7l/libsystemd-shared-232.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/systemd/v7l", 0xbed08cc0)  = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/systemd/neon/vfp/libsystemd-shared-232.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/systemd/neon/vfp", 0xbed08cc0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/systemd/neon/libsystemd-shared-232.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/systemd/neon", 0xbed08cc0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/systemd/vfp/libsystemd-shared-232.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/systemd/vfp", 0xbed08cc0)  = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/systemd/libsystemd-shared-232.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib/systemd/libgcc_s.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgcc_s.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib/systemd/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib/systemd/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libselinux.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcap.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/librt.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/liblzma.so.5", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/liblz4.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgcrypt.so.20", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libacl.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libidn.so.11", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libseccomp.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpcre.so.3", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgpg-error.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libattr.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
statfs("/sys/fs/selinux", 0xbed0a2a4)   = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
statfs("/selinux", 0xbed0a2a4)          = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/proc/filesystems", O_RDONLY)     = 3
access("/etc/selinux/config", F_OK)     = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/locale.alias", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/usr/lib/locale/C.UTF-8/LC_IDENTIFICATION", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/gconv/gconv-modules.cache", O_RDONLY) = 3
open("/usr/lib/locale/C.UTF-8/LC_MEASUREMENT", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/usr/lib/locale/C.UTF-8/LC_TELEPHONE", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/usr/lib/locale/C.UTF-8/LC_ADDRESS", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/usr/lib/locale/C.UTF-8/LC_NAME", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/usr/lib/locale/C.UTF-8/LC_PAPER", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/usr/lib/locale/C.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/usr/lib/locale/C.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/SYS_LC_MESSAGES", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/usr/lib/locale/C.UTF-8/LC_MONETARY", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/usr/lib/locale/C.UTF-8/LC_COLLATE", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/usr/lib/locale/C.UTF-8/LC_TIME", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/usr/lib/locale/C.UTF-8/LC_NUMERIC", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/usr/lib/locale/C.UTF-8/LC_CTYPE", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/proc/self/stat", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
stat64("/proc/1/root", 0xbed0a108)      = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
open("/sys/fs/kdbus/1000-user/bus", O_RDWR|O_NOCTTY|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
Failed to start kiosk.service: Unit kiosk.service not found.
+++ exited with 5 +++
```

I do not find the attempt to access the file ...

-- ADDED 2 --

I missed to type `systemctl --user daemon-reload`.
Now the service is found but nothing happens.

```
linaro@tinkerboard:~/.config/systemd/user$ systemctl --user status kiosk
● kiosk.service - Kiosk launcher as service
   Loaded: loaded (/home/linaro/.config/systemd/user/kiosk.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2022-07-22 15:01:55 CEST; 2min 28s ago
  Process: 3489 ExecStart=/usr/bin/chromium (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 3489 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jul 22 15:01:54 tinkerboard systemd[1184]: Started Kiosk launcher as service.
Jul 22 15:01:55 tinkerboard systemd[1184]: kiosk.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jul 22 15:01:55 tinkerboard systemd[1184]: kiosk.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jul 22 15:01:55 tinkerboard systemd[1184]: kiosk.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

-- ADDED 3 --

I added the --enable-logging on the command line and a log debug is generated.

```
[4837:4837:0722/155433.606728:WARNING:browser_main_loop.cc(297)] Gtk: cannot open display:
```

Is the display variable missed?  Why?

-- UPDATE --

I modified the ExecStart to run a script. added the DISPLAY variable on the command line in the script.

```
[Unit]
Description = Kiosk launcher as service
After = pulseaudio.service
Wants = 
Requires = 

[Service]
Type = simple
ExecStart = /home/amtek/launchService.sh
Restart = always

[Install]
WantedBy = graphical-session.target
```

If I manually run the service by `systemctl --user start kiosk` the browser starts. If I close the browser, the browser restarts.

But If I reboot the machine, the browser is not automatically started and I'm not able to find any error message in dmesg or syslog.

The only clue is:

```
linaro@tinkerboard:~$ systemctl --user status kiosk
● kiosk.service - Kiosk launcher as service
   Loaded: loaded (/home/linaro/.config/systemd/user/kiosk.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

Comment: `Cannot open display` leads me to think you didn't specify the `DISPLAY` variable.

Answer (score 3):

This is running on systemd's `--system` bus.  We know that because your service file is in `/etc/systemd/system`.  The problem is that `root` usually doesn't have a desktop session.  Even if root had one (or more) desktop sessions, you would need to define which session to display this window on.

Run this on systemd's `--user` bus instead.  That will cause chromium to run as your logged-in user (instead of running as root). More importantly, it will cause the service's environment to inherit the logged-in user's `DISPLAY` and `XAUTHORITY` environment variables.

To run on the `--user` bus:

1. Move `kiosk.service` file to `~/.config/systemd/user/`.  If that directory doesn't exist, create it.
2. Set your `WantedBy=` to something that exists on the user-bus.  The best case is to use `graphical-session.target`.  This will cause chromium to launch only after your desktop is ready.  This works for most (but not all) desktop environments.  If you are using something that hasn't implemented graphical-session.target (or perhaps you are calling `xinit` yourself), then use `WantedBy=default.target`.
3. Test your service with `systemctl --user start kiosk.service` (don't use `sudo`)

Alternatively, you could continue to run this on the `--system` bus, but you would need to set:

1. `Environment=DISPLAY=:0 XAUTHORITY=/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority` (replacing the values with what is relevant to your display).
2. `WantedBy=graphical.target` to ensure this only starts after you have a display running
3. `User=kioskuser` to avoid giving your users root permissions.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was also trying the --user way but I always receive *Failed to start kiosk.service: Unit kiosk.service not found* but the file is there, under the ~/.config/systemd/user folder.

Comment: People often get that error if they run `sudo systemctl --user ...`.  That's because `sudo` will look in `/root/.config...`.  Avoid using `sudo` when working with the user-bus.

Comment: I'm not using ```sudo ..```

Comment: Does the service file have particular rights?

Comment: Does the location of `~` match the location of `$HOME`? Do you have `kiosk.service` in a sub-directory (don't do that)? Does `kiosk.service` have the `.service` extension?  If you aren't using sudo, check the spelling of your paths. `~/.config/systemd/user/*` is hard-coded into `systemd`, so being unable to find that file isn't a systemd problem.  See [systemd.unit(5)](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html) for a list of places `systemd` looks to find the file.

Comment: it needs to be user-readable.  Mine are all 644 (umask 0022) which is pretty normal when creating a file.